# How to find the number of weeks in that month given month of the year?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.3

Given that I have month and year in 'YYYY-MM' format, how do I find the number of weeks in that month?

e.g. 2014-07 has 5 weeks.

I think the idea is to find the last date of the month and then finding the week of the month of that date. The following works if I put in a proper date,  but I'm not sure how to reconstruct a date/timestamp given that my starting point is YYYY-MM.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp '2014-07-31') 
    + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', 'w' )
```

Thank you!

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to do 
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', timestamp '2014-07-31')  + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', 'w' )
  
but i wasnt sure how to do it without a date

Comment: Add your code to the question (use the *edit* link under the question) and someone will come help you :)

Comment: thanks for the feedback! my first time posting on SO :)

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to define "weeks". Is a calendar week that's partially within a month a "week"? Do you want complete 7-day periods? What? Do weeks begin on Sunday or Monday?

Do you want [ISO weeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)? Weeks according to some local financial rules? something else?

You must *clearly define the problem* before you can solve it. Often simply defining it helps you solve it.

---

Given date `d` of format `YYYY-MM` and data type `text`, this makes the first day of the month:

```
to_date(d, 'YYYY-MM');
```

then to get the last day, find the next month and subtract a day:

```
(to_date(d, 'YYYY-MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT (to_date('2014-07', 'YYYY-MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2014-07-31 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

From there you can do what you need to identify the weeks according to the definition appropriate for your application, e.g.:

```
regress=> SELECT extract(week from (to_date('2014-07', 'YYYY-MM') + INTERVAL '1' MONTH) - INTERVAL '1' DAY) - extract(week from to_date('2014-07', 'YYYY-MM'));
 ?column? 
----------
        4
(1 row)
```

according to one definition of "number of weeks".

Comment: thanks! yes, weeks of the month in my case refer to Mon-Sun, and partial week within a month is counted as a week. Thanks for your advice and help! :)